# How can I add my own reference to a DocuSign Envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm creating an envelope through the SDK, and listening for the signed result via the webhook, but how can I link it back to my original database record? I see the `Envelope` class has an `ExternalEnvelopeId` property, but even though I set it, it's not returned in the webhook and I don't see it as an option to include. Is there a way to return it, or is there another alternative way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do this, using [Custom Fields](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?bundleId=gbo1643332197980&topicId=poe1578456285890.html&_LANG=enus&language=en_US&rsc_301). I was able to set one or more at the time of creating the envelope, and then to retrieve them from the payload returned via the webhook. Be sure to include them in the payload the webhook sends (in the DocuSign backend you can select what must be attached to the payload).